# Advice needed for AWS set up

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am new with AWS stuff so here is my application requirement.

1. Node Js with express js
2. Mysql Database
3. PHP web application + API application

So how do I need to deploy it on AWS for a basic start so that after testing the platform I can deploy my production on it. So can you guys help me for:

1. How many instances are needed
2. What if I need to go with CentOS + cPanel hosting for mysql and PHP application

Comment: Not enough information to answer your question. Too general. Start with a minimum of instances

Answer (score 0):

you can go for plain 1 VM in AWS for start and if you tell about how much concurrent user are expected on your apps so we can help you to determine the resources.

Comment: It will start from 7 to 10 users for initial month and we are targeting 100 concurrent users by 2 months.

Comment: 1 vm is more then enough for this type of usage and go with least resources